# The javascript thing is weird. I don't know if that happens

Tags: nlp

i found  strange  result  of javascript

```
javascript
```

```
var a=123e65;
console.log(a);
```

```
javascript
```

result:1.23e+67 ;
why..this..?

I started studying JavaScript. During the study, I found strange results during various attempts. I can't figure out how to get that result...

Answer (score 1):

Well, the result is correct. Its math: in your variable `a`, the value is 123e65 (that `e` before the 65 means "raised to the base 10". So the value 123e65 = 123x10^65).

***In scientific notation, only numbers between 1 and 10 are valid. Ex: 1500 -> 1.5e3 or 1.5x10^3***

in the value of your variable `a`, you are exponentiating a number greater than 10, (in this case, 123 exponentiated to 65). So javascript just adjusts that number, that is, it leaves 123 as a number between 1 and 10 (returning two places to the left 123 -> 1.23).
To compensate for this two-place return ( 123 -> 1.23) he adds two more numbers in exponentiation (65 -> 67).

So what used to be 123e65 or 123x10^65 became 1.23e67 or 1.23x10^67

Answer (score 0):

This is because the value of variable is being converted to scientific format. Here, e represents '10 to the power'.

Hence, the output is coming as 1.23*10^67